# Problem in numpy operation for a 2*2 list

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crb4R.png)

I wrote a code for 2D list.

```
row_num = int(input())
col_ = int(input())
arr2=[]
for i in range(row_num):
    arr2.append([])
    a=input()
    a=a.split(" ")
    for j in range(col_):
        arr2[i].append(a[j])
for j in range(2):
  arr2[j][-2]=float(arr2[j][-2])-float(arr2[j][-1])
print(arr2)
```

first I didn't convert list into np array so my output was

```
2
2
2 9
2 9
[[-7.0, '9'], [-7.0, '9']]
```

but when I convert list into np array and do same operation

```
row_num = int(input())
col_ = int(input())
arr2=[]
for i in range(row_num):
    arr2.append([])
    a=input()
    a=a.split(" ")
    for j in range(col_):
        arr2[i].append(a[j])
arr2=np.array(arr2)   #here I am converting list into np array
for j in range(2):
  arr2[j][-2]=float(arr2[j][-2])-float(arr2[j][-1])
print(arr2)
```

I got different output

```
2
2
2 9
2 9
[['-' '9']
 ['-' '9']]
```

I don't know, why I am getting different answers?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `numpy.array()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array) says, for its parameter `dtype`:

> The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence. ...

This is exactly what happened here. You were expecting the array to be able to hold both `str` and `float` values, like ordinary Python arrays do; for this the `dtype` should be `object`. Since you didn't specify the type, it chose single characters instead:

```
>>> np.array(['2', '9'])
array(['2', '9'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

And then when you tried to put `-7.0` into one slot of an array of single characters, it must have turned it into a string `'-7.0'` and only used the first character of that.

So specify the `dtype` you want for your array when you create it. If you're looking to gain some of the performance advantages of Numpy, you probably want to use a floating-point `dtype` and convert your strings into floats *before* you put them into the Numpy array. Or you could do the conversion with `astype()`:

```
>>> np.array(['2', '9']).astype(float)
array([ 1.,  2.])
```